# Loading of Master pages dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can we have the Masterpage loaded dynamicallu. I have a page that must be used in 2 different scenarios ie., using two different master pages.

Appreciate all your help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your page you can write

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/AlternateMasterPage.master";
}
```

to change which one it will use

Comment: Is worth stating that this can only be done in the `PreInit` event of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you probably can, but it'll have to be rather early in the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) if possible.

However, depending on what the "two different scenarios" are, you might be able to get away with one. For example, if you require showing/hiding controls (login, logout, etc) based on a user's authentication state (anonymous, authenticated, or in a particular role/group), then you might consider using a [`LoginView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control instead. From a maintenance perspective, that might make things better if it still meets the requirements.

Edit: As per advice on the comment below - you would need to change the master page on the `PreInit` event.